# Две модели и carrierwave

Tags: ruby, upload, ruby-on-rails

Вообщем есть две модели `Content(name, desc, etc ...)` и `Files(id_content, file)`
`Content (has_many :files)` `Files(belongs_to :content)`. То есть сам класс аплоада должен работать с полем file модели Files, а инфа о файле должна заносится в Content. Покажите, пожалуйста, как примерно должно выглядеть действие create в такой ситуации и форма. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @RubyNub, интересно подвести итог по этому вопросу. Вы нашли решение?

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, не знаю, как обстоят дела именно с carrierwave, но с paperclip примерно так:

```
  def new
    @content = Content.new
    @content.files.build
  end
```

Модель:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :files, :allow_destroy => true
```

Форме проставьте

```
:html => { :multipart => true }
```

И дальше

```
<%= frm.fields_for :files do |file| %>
```

Comment: Вопрос то был про carrierwave, а вы про paperclip (один про Фому, а другой про Ерёму).

Comment: __@Чад__, вас не затруднит преобразовать ваш комментарий в ответ так, чтобы ваш ответ оказался исчерпывающим по данному вопросу (можно ещё прописать "как выглядит действие create...")? Сейчас вопрос в целом выглядит заброшенным, так как ответ "по аналогии с Paperclip" и без описания действия create явно нельзя назвать полноценным (коротко: ответ неполный/нечёткий, ответ не принят).

Answer (score 1):

К ответу [[@mikh](/users/6908/mikh)](/users/6908/mikh), надо добавить что:

в подблоке `frm.fields_fo` надо указывать

```
<%= file.file_field :file%>
<%= file.hidden_field :file_cache %>
```

согласно [документации](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

Так же надо указать в модели `File`

```
mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
```

Ну и сделать сам аплоадер. Всё в доке подробно описано :-)